# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.acme.dao.EmployeeDao

Tags: eclipse, spring, jboss7.x, classnotfoundexception

I created a project using JSF 2.0 and Spring, but after running it using JBoss 7.1, I encountered this exception:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.acme.dao.EmployeeDao from [Module "com.sun.jsf-impl:main" from local module loader @1f3eab7 (roots: C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules)]

The class `EmployeeDao.java`:

```
public interface EmployeeDao
{
    public void save(Employee employee);
    public Employee findById(int id);
    public List<Employee> findAll();
    public void update(Employee p);
    public void remove(int id);
}
```

In fact, the class Test works with fine:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-configuration.xml");
        EmployeeDao employeeDao = (EmployeeDao)context.getBean("EmployeeDaoImpl");

        Employee employee = new Employee("Albert","Einshtein");
        employeeDao.save(employee);

        Employee emp = employeeDao.findById(1);
        System.out.println("The employee is: " + emp);


        List<Employee> les = employeeDao.findAll(); 
        for (Employee e : les) 
        { 
            System.out.println("List of Employees is: " + e.getName() + " " + e.getCountry()); 
        }

        Employee e = employeeDao.findById(5);
        e.setName("Casandra");
        e.setCountry("Munich");
        employeeDao.update(e);

        employeeDao.remove(4);

        ((ConfigurableApplicationContext)context).close();

    }
```

Here is a screenshot displaying the structure of my project:

[image]

After running my project, the list of employees is displayed, but once I click on the `Add` button (on top at left of list page), the exception is displayed:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes Kukeltje, that class is available: I added it to my question. I didn't know the cause of this exception, however, the same project is worked as well with Tomcat6,7, Wildfly8,10 and the running of class test finish with success.

Comment: Sorry Kukeltje for that confusion: I changed the exception (EmployeeDao instead of BookDao) I added a picture approving the availability of that class.Could you please take a look about that.Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think there's problem with JSF, Could you please tell me if I'm right. Thanks in advance @Kukeltje

Comment: Sorry, next to impossible (at least for me). The reason is not visible from the code you posted, and since I'm not using spring I cannot even try to reproduce. And even if you had a [mcve], I would not invest time in it (due to the spring stuff). So I can only help you improve your question, sorry (I'll clean up the earlier comments)

Comment: The error message says 'com.acme.dao.EmployeeDao', the picture you showed us has 'com.jcg.dao.EmployeeDao'. Check your spring-configuration.xml for the incorrect reference.